# How to display twitter search parse?

Tags: twitter

My first question with Stackoverflow. How do I display/read twitter search parse data in my webpage?

Below is the code I am working with. I can see 15 object in console.log() but I have no idea on how to show this in web page view.

My coding is below:

$

```
.ajax({  
    url : "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=gaga&callback=?", 
    dataType : "json",  
    timeout:1000,  
    success : function(data)  
    {
        console.log(data.results);
        //console.log(data.results);
        //$('#twitter').html(data);// parse data here  


    },  
    error : function()  
    {  
            alert("Failure!");  
    },  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/2cxfN/

```
$.ajax({  
    url : "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=gaga&callback=?", 
    dataType : "json",  
    timeout:1000,  
    success : function(data)  
    {
        console.log(data.results);
        //console.log(data.results);
        //$('#twitter').html(data);// parse data here  
        $.each(data.results, function(i,o){
            console.log(o);
            $('<img/>', {src:o.profile_image_url}).appendTo('body');
            $('<div/>').text(o.from_user).appendTo('body');
        });

    },  
    error : function()  
    {  
            alert("Failure!");  
    },  
});​
```

Ah, I see you have a div with an id twitter - you would parse that HTML into what you want using the variables in each object that's in data.results, which I've extracted as o, then appendTo('#twitter');

Comment: Hi, I tried and it gives error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" What this means?

Comment: what exactly does this > **function(i,o)** means?